# Laravel : Search with posted parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel so please be patient with me.

i have to implement search functionality in Laravel. i am able to send form data to the search controller and receiving it as well

```
public function search_results(Request $request){
        if ($request->has('gender')) {
           echo $request->gender;
        }
        .....
}
```

Now when i am following tutorials on the web i am getting such examples :

```
public function filter(Request $request, User $user)
{
    // Search for a user based on their name.
    if ($request->has('name')) {
       $user->where('name', $request->input('name'))->get();
    }

}
```

or

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::where('status', 1)
                ->where('is_banned', 0)
                ->get(['name']);
    
    dd($users);
}
```

now i am not sure from where this  `User::` or `User $user` is being added, and what should i do in my scenario.

Your suggestions would be helpful ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $user represents an object belonging to the model(User::) associated with a table(users) in the mvc structure. If you want to "Search for a user based on their name." That means you already have a users table in database , and a User model .

You can use eloquent queries to retrieve data from database.

A User.php file should be generated when you create a new laravel project with composer. You can check for that.

So when you declare a variable like this :

```
$user = User::first();
```

You are actually getting the first element in 'users' table by using your User model.

If you can configure your User model and users table correctly , you should be able to get all records from your users table like this :

```
$users = User::all();
```

Then you can filter it like :

```
$users = $users->where('gender','male')      // where('gender',$request->gender) in your situation
```

If you dont have a users table or a model , you can look to the document about how to create models using artisan commands [Laravel API Doc. Generating Model Classes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#generating-model-classes)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i want to search on table called user_data and there is no model for that should i just create an empty model with same name and use it as Userdata::  ?? please confirm

Comment: laravel automatically matches table names and model names.

for example, the cars table automatically matches the car model. If you want to use auto matching in this way, you should update the table names as plural of the model. Or you can check how to match a different name table with the model on the internet.

Comment: As far as I understand from your questions, you have missing essential points. I strongly recommend that you take a look at the Laravel document, albeit from above.